# Two Models in One View, Validate only one of them

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, view, model

I have a View that contains a ParentModel, which contains 2 Models.
I only want to validate the fields of one or the other. Not both.
Let´s say I have:

```
public ParentModel{
  public BlueUser BlueUser {get; set;}
  public GreenUser GreenUser {get; set;}
}
```

So the user selects either he is a GreenUser or a BlueUser. Each type of user has different fields, and depending which type of User the user selects, I want to only validate the fields on that specific type of user.
How can this be achieved?

EDIT:
Both forms/models must be on the same View, maybe with some JQuery or Partials?

Comment: you can always just build a form for the appropriate type of user

Comment: But the 2 forms have to be on the same view...that´s how the client wants it and they even provided me with the Illustrator layouts.

Comment: then maybe you should edit your question and provide more info..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create one form with `HtmlHelper<BlueUser>` and the other with `HtmlHelper<GreenUser>`, and make them post to different actions.

First, the view model is:

```
@model ParentModel
```

Then use `HtmlHelperFor` to create an HtmlHelper for each of the submodels:

```
@{
   var blueHtml = Html.HtmlHelperFor(Model.BlueUser);
   var greenHtml = Html.HtmlHelperFor(Model.GreenUser);
}

@using (blueHtml.BeginForm("BluePost", null)) {
   @blueHtml.EditorForModel()
}

@using (greenHtml.BeginForm("GreenPost", null)) {
   @greenHtml.EditorForModel()
}
```

Lastly, in the controller create a diferent POST action for each form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BluePost(BlueUser model) {
   ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GreenPost(GreenUser model) {
   ...
}
```

Here's the extension method:

```
public static class HtmlHelperFactoryExtensions {

   public static HtmlHelper<TModel> HtmlHelperFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper) {
      return HtmlHelperFor(htmlHelper, default(TModel));
   }

   public static HtmlHelper<TModel> HtmlHelperFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, TModel model) {
      return HtmlHelperFor(htmlHelper, model, null);
   }

   public static HtmlHelper<TModel> HtmlHelperFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, TModel model, string htmlFieldPrefix) {

      var viewDataContainer = CreateViewDataContainer(htmlHelper.ViewData, model);

      TemplateInfo templateInfo = viewDataContainer.ViewData.TemplateInfo;

      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlFieldPrefix))
         templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = templateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldPrefix);

      ViewContext viewContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext;
      ViewContext newViewContext = new ViewContext(viewContext.Controller.ControllerContext, viewContext.View, viewDataContainer.ViewData, viewContext.TempData, viewContext.Writer);

      return new HtmlHelper<TModel>(newViewContext, viewDataContainer, htmlHelper.RouteCollection);
   }

   static IViewDataContainer CreateViewDataContainer(ViewDataDictionary viewData, object model) {

      var newViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(viewData) {
         Model = model
      };

      newViewData.TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { 
         HtmlFieldPrefix = newViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix 
      };

      return new ViewDataContainer {
         ViewData = newViewData
      };
   }

   class ViewDataContainer : IViewDataContainer {

      public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Max, it's good to know about the HtmlHelperFor class. Sadly, the designer gave me the html markup so I had to code around it, i.e. I can't separate the HTML code in 2 forms. The layouts I were given are pretty messy. I ultimately used Fluid Validation to do a per case validation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

solution 1

what you do is use Dependency validation , its not built in by default, only the `Compare` attribute, you can build your own attributes, like required if radio button value was something or you could use something like [Mvc.ValidationTookit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/09/29/mvc-validationtookit-alpha-release-conditional-validation-with-mvc-3.aspx)

---

solution 2

when the user choose blue user for example you use javascript to check in the form submit event what did he choose depending on what he choose you will direct him to different actions with appropriate model passed as parameter

Answer (score 0):

**Server side implementation**

1. You should have two forms on view.
2. Each forms should goes to different action in controller on post.

**Client side implementation for animation**

1. You can use whatever JavaScript library u like to make one form disable and the other enable on mouse focus.